# rbind doing different things for single versus multiple arguments

Tags: r

I am new to R and came over code that uses `do.call("rbind", df.list)` to combine a list of data frames.

The data frames have arrays as columns and rbind does remove the arrays, but only if there are at least two elements in the list to combine.

Quick example:

```
> class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)), data.frame(a=array(3,4)))$a)
[1] "numeric"
> class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)))$a)
[1] "array"
```

Is this a bug in rbind? It appears if it is called with one argument, it does just return that argument, while if called with multiple, it does remove arrays.

How can I "unarray" such a data frame if length(df.list) == 1?

Example of what I need:

```
> df.list1 <- list(data.frame(a=array(1,2), b=array("a")), data.frame(a=array(3,4), b=array("b")))
> df.list2 <- list(data.frame(a=array(1,2), b=array("a")))
> df.combined1 <- do.call("rbind", df.list1)
> df.combined2 <- do.call("rbind", df.list2)
> class(df.combined1$a)
[1] "numeric"
> class(df.combined2$a)
[1] "array"
```

The goal is to have a data frame df.combined not having array columns independent whether df.list had one or multiple elements. The type and number of the data frame columns are unknown in advance.

Comment: No. You are misunderstanding the action of `$` which is actually a call to "[[" with the default of `drop=TRUE`. Read `?'[[' very carefully.

Comment: Sorry, BondedDust, I don't understand. `rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)))[['a', drop=FALSE]]` gives 
`Error in .subset2(x, ..2, exact = exact) : attempt to select less than one element`

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with:

```
class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)), data.frame(a=array(3,4))))
class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2))))
```

Both these have class of `data.frame`.

Now, as you noticed:

```
> class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)), data.frame(a=array(3,4)))$a)
[1] "numeric"
> class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)))$a)
[1] "array"
```

The first one is expected, however, second one is unexpected due to the way `rbind` method for `data.frame`. As per the documentation for `rbind`:

> ... It [then] takes the classes of the columns from the first data frame,...

If you want to coerce the class in case of a single `array` to `numeric`, then you can use something like this:

```
ifelse(length(df.list) == 1,
       class(rbind(data.frame(a=as.vector(array(1,2))))$a),
       ...)
```

Coercing it `as.vector` gets rid of the `array` class. 
(**EDIT**: Depending on what you want, you might also benefit from the discussion in the comments below!)

Lastly, note that this is an issue only for a one-dimensional `array`. For higher dimensions, you get the appropriate class:

```
class(rbind(data.frame(a=array(as.numeric(1:10),c(2,5))))$a.1)
```

**EDIT**: Based on your update, I think here is what you want:

```
df.list1 <- list(data.frame(a=array(1,2), b=array("a")), data.frame(a=array(3,4), b=array("b")))
df.list2 <- list(data.frame(a=array(1,2), b=array("a")))

cobmineDFList <- function(df.list) {
  temp <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
  if(class(temp$a) == "array") temp$a <- as.numeric(temp$a)
  temp
}

df.combined1 <- cobmineDFList(df.list1)
df.combined2 <- cobmineDFList(df.list2)

class(df.combined1$a)
class(df.combined2$a)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Couldn't you just do `as.numeric(rbind(data.frame(a=array(1,2)))$a)` instead of the `ifelse`?

Comment: Sure you can. In fact you don't even need `rbind` in that case. You can do something even simpler: `as.numeric(array(1,2))`. However, based on the description, it seems like @stracktracer wants to fit this piece in a predefined structure.

Comment: @Richard: At this point I do not know what columns the data frame has and which types they have. I just need `do.call("rbind", df.list)` to behave equally (removing arrays from the columns), independent whether ` length(df.list)`  is 1 or > 1.

Comment: If the solution above is not working, plz provide some test data to reproduce this!

Comment: @Shambho I amended my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I used: `if length(df.list == 1) { df <- df.list[[1]]; col.classes <- sapply(df, class); df[col.classes == "array"] <- lapply(df[col.classes == "array"], as.vector) } else { df <- do.call("rbind", df.list)}`